# How to upload multiple images in java(struts) using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have jsp code

college.jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action ="/college.do">
<fieldset>
<legend>COLLEGE INFORMATION :</legend>
<pre>
Gallery Images: <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple/>
<html:submit value = "S U B M I T"/>
</fieldset>
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to upload the multiple images in struts

Total images storing folder in project

using this jsp,but i want to CollegeAction class and CollegeForm class how to do that 
please help me code

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do something like this. In your jsp file

```
<html:file property="image1"/>
<html:file property="image2"/>
<html:file property="image3"/>
```

Dont forget to set your html form's attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Then in your `Form` file, create your image variables:

```
private FormFile image1;
private FormFile image2;
private FormFile image3;
```

..along with their getters and setters.

You can then use the variables for image creation in your server side:

```
OutputStream bos = null;
InputStream stream = null;
try {
  String fileName = form.getImage().getFileName();
  String directory = "C:/your_folder";
  File f = new File(directory);
   if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdir();

   if (!"".equals(fileName)) {
    stream = form.getImage1().getInputStream();
    bos = new FileOutputStream(directory + fileName);
    int bytesRead = 0;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

     while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
      bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
    }
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this is ok but i want to a single (<html:file property="image1"/>) line taking the multiple images